# Error in Provider react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When i'm run my simple program

**Index.js**

```
function test(state = []) {
    return state
}

const store = createStore(test);

render( <Provider store = { store } >
    <App / > < /Provider > ,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
   return ( <h1 > Yo < /h1>)
}

export default App;
```

i get something like this:

```
Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at Object.onlyChild [as only] (onlyChild.js:33)
    at Provider.render (Provider.js:49)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:795
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
```

What i'm do wrong? 
When i delete Provider program render App

Comment: Can you specify imports and separate the files in the code sample ?

Comment: can't edit my question, i'll answear in comment.
index.js 
`
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './components/App'

App.js
import React from 'react' `

Comment: check if App is not null with a console log or debugger to make sure you are importing it right

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when you have more than one children retrieved (for example, if you render a component that has several elements but isn't wrapped in a div). Now I can't say much from looking at only the code above, try to wrap the content inside `<Provider ... />` in a `<div>`

Comment: I have tried this variant.

render( < 
Provider store = { store } > { 
() => ( < div > < span > Hero < /span> </div > ) 
} < /Provider > , 
document.getElementById('root') 
) 

But it too won't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with the content of the <Provider /> component?

Answer (score 0):

Your store should be an object, not an array. Change your test reducer to

```
function test(state = {}) {
    return state
}
```

You can store array values *in* your store but it needs to be an object at the top level.

```
{
  stuff: ['a', 'b'],
}
```